# Tensorflow 2.0.: ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found

Tags: tensorflow

I just installed tensorflow 2.0 using the pip command:

```
pip install tensorflow-gpu==2.0.0-alpha0
```

The import error is shown as follows:

```
import tensorflow as tf
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<ipython-input-1-64156d691fe5>", line 1, in <module>
    import tensorflow as tf

  File "C:\Anaconda\Anaconda3.7\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\__init__.py", line 27, in <module>
    from tensorflow._api.v2 import audio

  File "C:\Anaconda\Anaconda3.7\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\_api\v2\audio\__init__.py", line 8, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python.ops.gen_audio_ops import decode_wav

  File "C:\Anaconda\Anaconda3.7\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\__init__.py", line 49, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python import pywrap_tensorflow

  File "C:\Anaconda\Anaconda3.7\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow.py", line 74, in <module>
    raise ImportError(msg)

ImportError: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Anaconda\Anaconda3.7\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow.py", line 58, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python.pywrap_tensorflow_internal import *
  File "C:\Anaconda\Anaconda3.7\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py", line 28, in <module>
    _pywrap_tensorflow_internal = swig_import_helper()
  File "C:\Anaconda\Anaconda3.7\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py", line 24, in swig_import_helper
    _mod = imp.load_module('_pywrap_tensorflow_internal', fp, pathname, description)
  File "C:\Anaconda\Anaconda3.7\lib\imp.py", line 242, in load_module
    return load_dynamic(name, filename, file)
  File "C:\Anaconda\Anaconda3.7\lib\imp.py", line 342, in load_dynamic
    return _load(spec)
ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found.


Failed to load the native TensorFlow runtime.
```

The installation was done on the Windows 10 with python 3.7.1, and cuda 9.0. 
I have successfully installed tensorflow-gpu 1.13 on my pc in the python 3.5 environment. It seems tensorflow 2.0 is compatible with python 3.7 [Ultimate Guide to TensorFlow 2.0 in Python](https://rubikscode.net/2019/04/22/ultimate-guide-to-tensorflow-2-0-in-python/)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TF2.0 was built with CUDA 10 in mind. [source](https://www.tensorflow.org/install/gpu)

You either can install CUDA 10.0 with cuDNN SDK (>= 7.4.1) or build Tensorflow from sourse.